# How do i implement observables depending on a rule template provided by an object

Tags: typescript, observable

The idea is pretty simple: 
I have certain rules hold by an JavaScript Object like so

```
ruleExample = {
  key1: ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'],
  key2: ['id1', 'id4'],
  key3: ['id5', 'id6', id7']
}
```

and a class representing objects that should be able to observe each other depending on a given ruleset like so

```
export class Item {
 private id: string;
 ... 

 constructor(id: string, private itemManager: ItemManager) {
   this.id = id;
   this.itemManager.register(this);
 }

 doSomething(){ ... }
}
```

and a class representing the manager of objects from the Item class above like so

```
export class ItemManager {
  private rules = {}  // from above
  private ruleSubjects = {}  // this will hold different rxjs Subjects accessible by rules.key's, these rules can differ so we need to fill later

  consturctor() {
  // create our ruleSubjects Array holding rules by name as Subject
    for ( const key in this.rules) {
      if (!this.rules.hasOwnProperty(key)) { continue; }
      this.ruleSubjects[key] = new Subject<string>();
      this.ruleSubjects[key + '$'] = this.ruleSubjects[key].asObservable();
    }
  }

  // subscribe item based on the ruleset at the right observable (this is simplified!)
  register(item: Item) {
    if (item.id === 'id1') {
      this.ruleSubjects[key1 + '$'].subscribe( item.id => { item.doSomething(); }); // id1 appears in rule key1
      this.ruleSubjects[key2 + '$'].subscribe( item.id => { item.doSomething(); }); // and in key2
    }
  }
}
```

So far so good. Now if `item = new Item('id1')` the itemManager should subscribe the item to the right Observers. Shouldn't it?

But i am getting these ERROR:

```
TS1005: ',' expected.
this.ruleSubjects.[key1 + '$'].subscribe( item.id => { item.doSomething(); }); 
                                                  ^^       ^^            ^^
```

What am i doing wrong? Thank you for helping!

Comment: `item.id => {` =>  `item => {`

Comment: hi @PranavCBalan let me check that and report back. an explanation would be great anyways.

Comment: incorrect syntax

Comment: sometimes i feel stupid, sometimes i feel more stupid, thank god i can laugh about myself :) thank you @PranavCBalan

Comment: hahhahaha sometimes it happens ;)